# convert tuples to a datatype in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having issues to convert a list with multiple tuples into a datatype

```
data SensorValue = SensorValue {a:: Integer, b:: Integer, c:: [Integer]} deriving (Show)
```

my list with tuples looks like this:

```
[(1, [(2, [3,4,5]), (2, [2,3,1]), (3, [2,3,7])]), (2, [(1, [4,4,1]), (2, [2,3,1]), (3, [9,0,3])]),...]
```

so basically my list looks like `[(Integer, [(Integer, [Integer])])]`

### Example

If I take the first tuple from my list `(1, [(2, [3,4,5])` then my expected output is:

a SensorValue object with :

```
a = 1       -- first element of the first tuple
b = 2       -- first element of the second tuple
c = [3,4,5] -- second element of the second tuple
```

I know how to get to the first tuple with `fst` but how do I get to the second tuple?

Comment: Wouldn't `snd` give you the second element of the tuple? Or am I missing something? Perhaps an example of your expected output would help.

Comment: @shree.pat18 how do I get the first element from the second tuple if you understand what I mean?

Comment: So from your list, you want to get b = 2 as the function output?

Comment: Can I check - with the list you have given in your question i.e. '[(1, [(2, [3,4,5]), (2, [2,3,1])...', how would you convert that to a `SensorValue`? Which of the tuples in the inner list should go to the b and c parts?

Comment: @shree.pat18 like this `[SensorValue {a = 1, b = 2, c = [3,4,5], SensorValue {a = 1, b = 2, c = [2,3,1]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching here. Your function would look something like this:

```
f :: (Integer,[(Integer,[Integer])]) -> [SensorValue]
f (x,((y,z):zs)) = SensorValue x y z : f (x,zs) -- First element same for all
f(x,[]) = []
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HDB4379)

You would still need to specify the conditions to handle other cases e.g. What happens if the list that forms the second element of the outer tuple is empty?

Comment: as an input I expect a list of tuples. Not just 1 tuple

Comment: Like I said before, you can simply map this function over a list as my demo shows. I'm trying to avoid pattern matching on tuples inside lists to reduce the complexity.

Comment: That `f (x,[])` clause looks really weird; my first instinct would be `f (x,[]) = []`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point! I will edit my answer to update it.

Comment: Is it possbile to have only 1 list as an output instead of lists in a list?

Comment: Sure, use `concatMap` instead of `map` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions or do syntax make this quite nice -- assuming you understand them!

```
doSyntax, listComprehensions :: [(Integer, [(Integer, [Integer])])] -> [SensorValue]

doSyntax sensorPoints = do
    (a, pointsAtA ) <- sensorPoints
    (b, valuesAtAB) <- pointsAtA
    return (SensorValue a b valuesAtAB)

listComprehensions sensorPoints =
    [ SensorValue a b valuesAtAB
    | (a, pointsAtA ) <- sensorPoints
    , (b, valuesAtAB) <- pointsAtA
    ]
```

Depending on just what you want to do, you might even consider storing just one sensor value in each element of the result list. Like this (with a variant on the naming scheme above, just for fun):

```
data SensorValue = SensorValue { a, b, val :: Integer }
fromRawData abvalM =
    [ SensorValue a b val
    | (a, bvalM) <- abvalM
    , (b,  valM) <-  bvalM
    , val        <-   valM
    ]
```